# Securing Carrierwave uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

want to make sure that ONLY users that are logged in can view/download files uploaded from carrierwave.

How is this done?

Moved store directory from public to RAILS_ROOT, created route to show and download.

Problem is if its an image, `<%= image_tag(photo.image_url) %>` I get the full path /Users/myname/projects/appname/files/image/id/image.png, so that doesn't render.

Also, would be nice if view would not render my absolute path, just relative path from site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a really easy thing to do. Here's a blog that talks about sendfile and x-sendfile. This should send you in the right direction.

http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right

Here is the rails docs for it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file

Since this is all handled at the controller level, just make sure you have a before_filter that checks if the user is authorized, then use the send_file method in your controller action.

Comment: Have seen this article and requires that I move store_dir from public, but I think I'm doing something wrong.  store_dir is "/#{Rails.root.to_s}/files/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.customer_id}/#{model.id}".  Keep getting ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/Users/.../42/142/thumb_9-cars.jpg")

Comment: Yeah you won't have a route to the file using that path in the web app, that's why you are using send_file... so you can point it at a regular file system path. If carrierwave is storing the file in your filesystem, and the image_url is the right path. Everything should just work. Remember you are going to point your image tag at the path to the controller that is outputting the image, not the actual image path.